# Is there a minimalist Java compiler/debugger I can use (outside of an IDE)?

Tags: java, debugging, compiler-construction, text-editor

I don't really like how complicated it is to write and compile simple code in IDEs like Netbeans (making a new project, file, making packages, etc). I just want to write some code and then compile/debug it and then repeat. I'm not doing any serious project that warrants the use of Netbeans. Does there exist a minimalist compiler/debugger, or at the very least a super minimalist IDE?

Comment: You could compile it yourself with `javac`, but so far as debugging you'll quickly find that the IDE is crucial.

Comment: Most minimal you can get with a compiler is the built-in `javac`. Text editor -- go with your computer's built-in text editor. Debugging tool -- not really sure. Don't really know of a "minimal" IDE, as they all (or the most common ones at least) seem to pride themselves on lots of features

Comment: By built-in javac I assume you mean from the Windows Command Line, right? The only problem with that is I have to type/paste the address to the folder consisting of my files which would get really annoying.

Comment: You can always `cd` to the right folder. And the tab key is your friend on the command line.

Comment: You can always create a command prompt shortcut which starts in the right directory, too.

Comment: @Gavin: FYI, if you have a command prompt and Windows Explorer open, you can type `cd` followed by a space, then drag the address bar from Windows Explorer into the command prompt and drop it. It pastes in the directory path. And of course, you do that once when starting what you're doing, so not much of a barrier.

Answer (score 5):

Basic tools:

1. A compiler: The [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) comes with a command-line compiler, [`javac`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javac/). If it's not in your `PATH`, you can find it in the `bin` subdirectory of wherever you installed the JDK. (I typically add that directory to my `PATH`.) (If you didn't install the JDK yourself, it was installed by your IDE; you may want to do a "normal" installation yourself.)
2. A way to run the results: You're probably used to using the `java` tool from the JRE for running compiled classes, unless you've always done that in an IDE too.
3. A debugger: While the JDK comes with a command-line debugger, [`jdb`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html), it's a completely different and alien world if you're used to debugging in an IDE. For a fairly lightweight solution, I used [JSwat](https://github.com/nlfiedler/jswat) many years ago and was quite impressed.
4. A text editor: I'm sure you have your favorite.

Sample program:

```
public class Temp {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, Java!");
    }
}
```

Compiling at the command line (in my case on Linux, but other than the prompt it looks the same on Windows):

```
$ javac Temp.java
```

Running:

```
$ java Temp
Hello, Java!
```

Comment: Is there a program I can install that acts as a Command Line without my having to use Command Line? Otherwise I would need to set a default directory for cdr

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. (And what OS are you using?) Why can't you use the command-line from your OS? On Windows, the Command Prompt or PowerShell; on \*nix, any of several excellent shells like `bash`, `csh`, `ksh`, ...

Answer (score 0):

There's `javac`, of course, and for a minimalist debugger, you could try `jdb`.  I haven't used it in years, personally, but my recollection is that it did what I needed at the time.